# Как увеличить громкость до 200% с помощью Kotlin? (На Android)

Tags: android, kotlin

Как я могу увеличить громкость до 200% с помощью моего приложения Android? (Написано на Kotlin)

`AudioManager` не принимает 200%, только 100% и меньше

Я видел приложения которые это делают - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.soulapps.superloud.volume.booster.sound.speaker например (Не реклама)

Comment: 1 динамик 100%. 200% - 2 динамика.

Comment: Это как? В телефоне только 1 динамик, но я видел приложения которые повышают громкость без 2 динамика @Wlad

Comment: а как вы вообще можете сделать мощность чего-то больше 100%?

Comment: Нуу... Я сам не понимаю, но видел такие приложения в Play Market https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.soulapps.superloud.volume.booster.sound.speaker например @Wlad как они работают

Comment: Громкость может повышаться за счёт накрутки эквалайзера или другого "улучшителя" звука, но явно не в 2 раза и даже при этом среднестатистический телефонный динамик начинает хрипеть. Скорее всего подобные приложения лезут в настройки аппарата и крутят вышеозначенные фичи.

Comment: @woesss а как изменять настройки эквалайзера и какие значения, я просто хочу сделать похожее приложение